# How do I limit the amount of tasks allowed to input in my task list?

Tags: php, sql

my question is related to PHP/SQL.

I know how to limit the results returned by using 'LIMIT 5'. How do I limit the allowed input? So that a user can't add more tasks until he deletes one of the existing ones? So basically how do I limit the input instead of the results. At this moment I can still add tasks, but with only the limited results it pushes the older tasks out of view. I want it to be impossible to add more tasks unless one is deleted when it has reached the list limit.

**UPDATE: Shared code:**

(Yes, I know I need to use prepared statements)

Head:

```
<?php 
    $errors = "";

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "certanet");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['task'])) {
            $errors = "";
        }else{
            $task = $_POST['task'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (task) VALUES ('$task')";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            header('location: dashboard.php');
        }
  } 
  
  if (isset($_GET['del_task'])) {
    $id = $_GET['del_task'];
  
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=".$id);
    header('location: dashboard.php');
  }

  ?>
```

Tasklist:

```
<div class="todobox">
<div class="menutitle" id="category">
    Persoonlijke takenlijst
</div>
<div class="inhoud">
Hieronder is het mogelijk om je eigen taken bij te houden.

<form method="post" action="dashboard.php" class="input_form">
<?php if (isset($errors)) { ?>
    <p><?php echo $errors; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
        <input type="text" name="task" class="task_input">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Toevoegen</button>
    </form>
  <table>

    <tbody id="todo">
        <?php 
        $tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");

        $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                <td class="task"> <?php echo $row['task']; ?> </td>
                <td class="delete"> 
                    <a href="dashboard.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">x</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>    
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

[image: The tasklist widget]

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: This sounds like something more to do with the front end where a user puts the values in than the database.

Comment: I mean if the tasklist already has, say limit 7 tasks, I don't want the user to be able to add more until he deletes one of the existing 7 tasks. If he tries that it will give an error like 'List is full!'. While I can design the error alert, I can't make it limit the input of the user.

Comment: Before you even show them the page to add more check and see how many the person already has. If they have their limit show the page that says sorry, no more until you delete some .... at that point showing them their tasks with a delete button for each one would probably be a good idea.

Comment: @Dave I know that's the logic behind it. My problem is, how can I limit the user to enter more than ex. 7 tasks on the backend.

Comment: You've stored them in the DB so count them before you show the page. Your query limits what you retrieve to 7 but I don't see you counting them to know if there are more than 7 and taking action if there are.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was missing. I'm still learning, so I assumed the results would also limit the input, but it just pushes the older ones out of view. Anyhow, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are asking for a solution in SQL, this is really more of an application / business requirement than a database concern. If the business logic of your application requires a limit on user-created records, then it is the application which should query for the existing number of records and present appropriate messaging to the user.

It's not apparent from your insert SQL whether the row being inserted into the `tasks` table includes a column to identify which user entered it. This may be fine if this is a single-user application, or perhaps your underlying framework handles this automatically. If neither of those is true, we'll need to add a column to that table to capture a user ID or other identifying information to associate each `task` record with its respective user (e.g., depending on your use case, IP address or a session ID may suffice).

Assuming the above is all true, there are a few changes we should implement:

1. Never display the form to the user, as this crates an **affordance** for functionality which is not supported/allowed. Instead, we'll replace the form with a message to provide appropriate feedback to the user.
2. If we receive a `POST` request from a user attempting to add a new record after they've exceeded the limit, reject the request and display a message to the user.
3. Add a `userId` column, or *some* datum to associate the user, to the `tasks` table.
4. Set the value of this new column when inserting new `tasks`.

Whether a `GET` or `POST`, we're going to want to query for the user's existing records before rendering the page.

```
<?php
$errors = "";
$maxUserTasks = 7;

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "certanet");

// Before even handling the request, query for the user's existing records
$sql = "SELECT task FROM tasks WHERE userId = 123"
$userTaskCountQuery = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$userTaskCount = $userTaskCountQuery->num_rows();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['task'])) {
        $errors = "";
    }else if ($userTaskCount > $maxUserTasks){
        $errors = "You already have $maxUserTasks tasks."
    }else{
        // Here is where you'll first want to check
        $task = $_POST['task'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (task) VALUES ('$task')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        header('location: dashboard.php');
    }
}

// Presumably, your page markup and form are somewhere down here
if ($userTaskCount > $maxUserTasks){
   // display our error message here
}else{
   // otherwise, display our form
}
?>
```